# The average value of the modulus $|f(z)|$ of a polynomial with real coefficients

Tags: cv.complex-variables, probability-distributions

This question just came in my mind and I don't know whether this or similar questions have been considered in the literature. Consider a complex-valued polynomial $$p(z)=a_0+a_1z+\dots+a_nz^n$$  of degree n with with given coefficients. If $z$ is chosen uniformly in the circle(disc) $|z| \leq 1$ ,then $Y=|p(z)|$ is obviously a random variable when z is uniformly chosen in the unit disc $|z| \leq 1$. Is it possible to find out the pdf of $Y$ or even some of the statistical measures like mean, variance etc. as functions of $n$ and of the coefficients or would that be too hard analytically? I have no idea as to how to proceed. Could someone kindly point out the relevant results in complex analysis that would bear something on this problem? I would  greatly appreciate any hints/suggestions/links in this regard.

 PS:-of course the distribution  of $Y$ will change as we vary the coefficients. So precisely speaking I am talking about the distribution of $Y$  given the coefficient vector $(a_0,a_1,...a_n)$. If you think prescribing some distribution to the coefficients will make it more interesting and meaningful, kindly write your response to that problem as well

Comment: doesn't the average of |p(z)| exist for a given vector of coefficients $(a_0,a_1,...,a_n)$?If we take the coefficients as per some distribution say,$N(0,1)$ would the problem make sense in that case ?

Comment: i need the average in terms of n and the coefficients which are assumed to b fixed and given,more specifically I need the distribution of $Y=|p(z)|$ given $(a_0,a_1,..,a_n)$

Comment: OK, so the even moments may be computed by integrating over the ball in polar coordinates.

Comment: @AlgebraicsAnonymous could you kindly explain how the moments can be computed?

Comment: Not the one you consider, but a well-studied quantity is the [Mahler measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahler_measure) of a polynomial $p$, which is the *geometric* mean of $|p|$ over the unit torus. There is also the [zeta Mahler function](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.09506) $Z(p,s)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\ol\overline$As pointed out by AlgebraicsAnonymous, it is not a problem to find all even-order moments of $Y$.

However, Mathematica cannot find $EY$ even when $n=1$, $a_0=1$, and $a_1=2$. So, it is highly unlikely that a closed form expression for $EY$ exists in general, let alone higher odd-order moments.

Here is the image of a corresponding Mathematica notebook:

[image]

**Remark 1:** The OP asked for details on how the above expression for mod (?) in the Mathematica notebook was derived. So, here is the derivation: for $z=re^{it}$ with $r\ge0$ and $t\in[0,2\pi)$,
\begin{equation*}   
\begin{aligned}
&   |p(z)|^2=\Re(|p(z)|^2) \\ 
&=\Re(p(z)\overline{p(z)}) \\ 
&=\Re\Big(\sum_{j=0}^n a_j z^j\,\sum_{k=0}^n \ol{a_k}\, \ol z^k\Big) \\ 
&=\Re\Big(\sum_{j,k=0}^n a_j \ol{a_k} z^j\, \ol z^k\Big) 
=\sum_{j,k=0}^n \Re(a_j \ol{a_k} z^j\, \ol z^k) \\ 
&=\sum_{j,k=0}^n \Re(a_j \ol{a_k} r^{j+k} e^{i(j-k)t)})
=\sum_{j,k=0}^n a_j a_k r^{j+k}\cos((j-k)t)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
if the $a_j$'s are real numbers (which is so in the case considered in the Mathematica notebook).

---

Of course, one can bound the odd-order moments of $Y$ using the log-convexity of $m_p:=EY^p$ in $p$:
\begin{equation*}
    m_{2q+2}^{3/2}m_{2q+4}^{-1/2}\le m_{2q+1}\le m_{2q}^{1/2}m_{2q+2}^{1/2} \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
for $q=0,1,\dots$.

**Remark 2:** The OP asked for details on how the log-convexity of $m_p$ in $p$ is used to get (1). Here we go: the log-convexity of $m_p$ in $p$ means that $l_p:=\ln m_p$ is convex in $p$, that is,
\begin{equation*}
    l_{p_t}\le (1-t)l_{p_0}+tl_{p_1}, \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
where $p_0$ and $p_1$ are any nonnegative real numbers, $t\in[0,1]$, and $p_t:=(1-t)p_0+tp_1$.
Using now (2) with $p_0=2q+1$, $p_1=2q+4$, and $t=1/3$ (and some simple algebra), we get the first inequality in (1). Using (2) with $p_0=2q$, $p_1=2q+2$, and $t=1/2$ (and some simple algebra), we get the second inequality in (1).

Note also the special case of the second inequality in (1) with $q=0$:
\begin{equation*}
    m_1\le m_2^{1/2}, \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
which is also an instance of the Cauchy--Schwarz, Lyapunov, and Hölder inequalities.

As for the even-order moments, using the multinomial expansion of $Y^{2q}=p(z)^q\overline{p(z})^q$ for $q=0,1,\dots$ and integrating the resulting expansion term-wise in polar coordinates, we get
$$m_{2q}=\frac{(q!)^2}{2\pi}\,
\sum_{s=0}^{nq}\frac1{s+1}
\sum\nolimits_s\prod_{j=0}^n\frac{a_j^{q_j}\,\overline{a_j}^{\,t_j}}{q_j!\, t_j!},$$
where $\sum\nolimits_s$ denotes the summation over all $(n+1)$-tuples $(q_0,\dots,q_n)$ and $(t_0,\dots,t_n)$ of nonnegative integers such that $\sum_{j=0}^n j q_j=\sum_{j=0}^n j t_j=s$.

Comment: @losif Panels, could you kindly explain where the expression for m in the  code comes from,I mean how you derive it

Comment: @sajjadveeri : There is no m in the code. I guess, you meant mod instead of m. Anyhow, I have added a detailed derivation for mod. Also, my last name is Pinelis, not Panels.

Comment: @losif Pinelis,apologies for misspelling ypur name  and thank you for the wonderful and lucid explanation.Could you kindly explain how you actually used the log-convexity in bounding the odd moments and why you divided by $\pi $ and not the area of the circle?Second ,I did some calculations and I found that  $|p(z)|^2$ can be computed  in a closed form,since $\int_0^{2 \pi}cos(j-k)t dt=0$  when j is not equal to k .In the rest of case we will be left with terms of the form $ \int_o^1 a_j^2 r^{2j}dr$ which are readily computable.

Comment: Am I right here?If yes ,can we bound  average of $|p(z)|$ using average of $|p(z)|^2$ ?thank you and regards

Comment: @sajjadveeri : I have provided details on the use of the log-convexity. Also, I have noted the inequality $m_1\le m_2^{1/2}$ (now inequality (3)) as a special case.

Comment: lots of thanks for your responce